# Show that $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges uniformly to the function $|x|$ in the interval $[-1,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let , $f_n(x)$ be a sequence of function such that $f_0(x)=0$ and $$f_{n+1}(x)=f_n(x)+\frac{1}{2}[x^2-f_n^2(x)].$$Show that $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges uniformly  to the function $|x|$ in the interval $[-1,1]$.

I want to use Dini's Theorem to prove it.

Firstly , suppose that $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges to $l(x)$ point-wise. Then , $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=l(x).$  Then , $l=l+\frac{1}{2}[x^2-l^2]\implies l=|x|$. So, $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges point-wise to a **continuous function** $|x|$. Now it is sufficient to show that $\{f_n(x)\}$ is a sequence of monotone function. That is we have to show that , $f_{n+1}-f_n(x)=\frac{1}{2}[x^2-f_n^2(x)]\ge0$ or $\le 0$ for all $n$.

Now $|f_n(x)-|x||<\epsilon$ for $n\ge n_0$ for some $n_0\in \mathbb N$. So, $|f_n(x)|<\epsilon +|x|<|x|\implies f_n^2(x)<x^2$ for $n\ge n_0$. Thus , $f_{n+1}-f_n(x)>0$ for $n\ge n_0$. i.e. $\{f_n(x)\}$ is monotone increasing for $n\ge n_0$.

> But how I can show that  $\{f_n(x)\}$ is monotone increasing for all $n$ ?

$$OR$$Another way to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$l(x) = l(x) + \frac{1}{2}(x^2 - l(x)^2)$$

alone does not imply that $l(x) = \lvert x\rvert$, it only implies $l(x)^2 = x^2$, so for every $x$, either $l(x) = x$ or $l(x) = -x$. To conclude $l(x) = \lvert x\rvert$ for all $x$, you need to conclude that $l(x) \geqslant 0$ for all $x$. Fortunately, that follows immediately from the monotonicity $f_{n+1}(x) \geqslant f_n(x)$, so requires no extra work.

However, your argument for the monotonicity of the sequence is wrong, you wrote

$$\lvert f_n(x)\rvert < \lvert x\rvert + \epsilon < \lvert x\rvert,$$

but for $\epsilon > 0$, the latter inequality is false.

To see that $f_{n+1} \geqslant f_n$, we need to see that $x^2 - f_n(x)^2 \geqslant 0$, which is equivalent to $\lvert f_n(x)\rvert \leqslant \lvert x\rvert$. Proving the monotonicity - and hence the non-negativity of all $f_n$ - by induction, in the induction hypothesis we can assume that $0 \leqslant f_n(x) \leqslant \lvert x\rvert$, and want to deduce $f_n(x) \leqslant f_{n+1}(x) \leqslant \lvert x\rvert$. As mentioned above, the left inequality here follows from the right, so we need only show that $f_{n+1}(x) \leqslant \lvert x\rvert$. To see that, write

\begin{align}
\lvert x\rvert - f_{n+1}(x) &= \lvert x\rvert - f_n(x) - \frac{1}{2}(x^2 - f_n(x)^2)\\
&= (\lvert x\rvert - f_n(x))\cdot \biggl(1 -\frac{1}{2}(\lvert x\rvert + f_n(x))\biggr)\\
&\geqslant 0
\end{align}

where the first factor in the penultimate line is non-negative as part of the induction hypothesis, and the second factor is non-negative since $f_n(x) + \lvert x\rvert \leqslant 2\lvert x\rvert \leqslant 2$ also as a consequence of the induction hypothesis.

Thus we have seen that

- The sequence $(f_n)$ is monotonically increasing and bounded (above) by $\lvert x\rvert$, whence it converges pointwise to some non-negative function.
- The limit function is $x \mapsto \lvert x\rvert$, so continuous, and by Dini's theorem, since $[-1,1]$ is compact, the convergence is uniform.

> But how I can show that $\{f_n(x)\}$ is monotone increasing for all $n$?

Does that mean you want to show that for every $n$ the function $f_n$ is monotonically increasing on $[-1,1]$? That isn't the case - it cannot be, for the pointwise limit of monotonically increasing functions is monotonically increasing, but $\lvert x\rvert$ isn't. And nothing in Dini's theorem requires that. The monotonicity in Dini's theorem is that for all $x$ and all $n$ one has $f_n(x) \leqslant f_{n+1}(x)$, how the values at different points are related is irrelevant.